# Spring http/web forward not working with spring-reactive

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am trying to forward a request from one controller to another, but instead I am getting an exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name
>   'forward:/test2'.     at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$5(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:272)
>   ~[spring-web-reactive-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]

Here are my controllers :

```
@Controller
class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "forward:/test2";
    }
}

@RestController
public class TestController2 {
    @RequestMapping(value="/test2")
    public String showTestPage() {
        return "testPageView";
    }
}
```

I am using spring-boot

> ```
> springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
>
> compile('org.springframework.boot.experimental:spring-boot-starter-web-reactive')
> ```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported at the moment.

Please create a new issue on https://jira.spring.io (project: Spring Framework, component: reactive). Some concepts don't really map into the reactive world, so I'm not 100% sure this should be implemented.

Comment: How to do a redirect to an external URL? See https://github.com/poutsma/web-function-sample/issues/7

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the `UrlBasedViewResolver` states that in order to forward to another view, you need to use the `redirect:` prefix, not "forward:"